# R: Unambiguous format when reading zoo and converting to with "as.POSIXct"

Tags: r, csv, format, time-series, zoo

I am trying to read some data into a `read.zoo` data, but always getting some error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

The code is:

```
df_zoo <- read.zoo("mydata.csv",
                header = TRUE,
                sep = ";",
                index = 1:2,
                FUN = paste,
                FUN2 = as.POSIXct,
                format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S",
                tz = "UTC",
                dec = ",")
```

The first lines of the log are

```
DATE;TIME_UTC;#1;#2;#3
14.06.2016;12:15:11;TRUE;TRUE;43,2
14.06.2016;12:15:12;TRUE;TRUE;43,3
14.06.2016;12:15:13;TRUE;TRUE;43,3
...
```

I could change the date in the CSV, but it should be doable in R and i don't want to change it for any further CSV. Also

```
as.POSIXct(paste("14.06.2016","12:15:11"), format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
```

is working just fine:

```
[1] "2016-06-14 12:15:11 UTC"
```

I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need 1 `FUN` line to define the function to paste col1 and col2:

`FUN = function(d,t) as.POSIXct(paste(d,t),format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S",tz = "UTC”)`

So to import your file as zoo object:

```
df_zoo <- read.zoo("mydata.csv",
                header = TRUE,
                sep = ";",
                index = 1:2,
                FUN = function(d,t) as.POSIXct(paste(d,t),format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S",tz = "UTC"),
                dec = ",")
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks Mr. Vollmeier. :) Anyway, whats the purpose of FUN and FUN2 then?

Comment: FUN2 can be handy if you have a more complex transformation that you want to do in 2 steps. FUN2 is applied to the time index after FUN and before `aggregate` . More information is available using `?read.zoo`. :-). If my suggested solution works, please consider to accept the solution by clicking on the tick mark next to the vote.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** `read.zoo` will automatically paste multi-column indexes together so this will work and does not use `FUN=` at all.  Note that zoo represents the data as a matrix and so in this case the logicals will be coerced to numeric.

```
library(zoo)
read.zoo("mydata.csv", check.names = FALSE,
  header = TRUE, sep = ";", comment = "", dec = ",",
  index = 1:2, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "")
```

**2)** `read.zoo` can also read data frames so this would work and takes advantage of the fact that many of the needed arguments are default arguments of `read.csv2`:

```
d <- read.csv2("mydata.csv", check.names = FALSE)
read.zoo(d, index = 1:2, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "")
```